# How to set y-axis to fixed range in rickshaw?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

I have data where most of the values are in range 41-44, but occasionally there are peaks to 150-350, so y-axis is automatically scaled to 0-350 and chart is simply unreadable.

How to set fixed min and max for y-axis? I know that some values will be "above" chart, but that is not a problem.

[Here is my chart](http://kartstat.com/graph/ironman_siedlce.html)

**EDIT:** alternatively I want to enable zooming in this graph which would be even better, any idea how to do this?

**EDIT2:** or maybe you can suggest other simple charting library with enabling/disabling lines, zooming & panning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have stumbled upon this question multiple times looking for a solution, Rickshaw now supports this itself by setting `min` and `max` in the graph constructor: https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw#rickshawgraph

Answer (score 4):

You could try using a scaled Y-axis (see the example in [scaled.html](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/scaled.html)).  Make sure to set the scale in the series object as well as in the Y-axis:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([41, 44]).nice();
graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
    ...
    series: [{
        ...
        scale: scale
    }]
});
new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.Scaled({
    graph: graph,
    ...
    scale: scale
});
```

I haven't tried zooming with Rickshaw, but if you provide a way for the user to control the zoom factor, I think you can change the domain in the scale and call `graph.update()`.

Answer (score -3):

I have used Giraffe - https://github.com/kenhub/giraffe that extends/built on top of rickshaw.
With that you can set a "min" and "max" for a chart to set the scale. Since Giraffe uses rickshaw underneath, there should be something similar on rickshaw.